# queryover and transformusing loses the ability to lazy load

Tags: nhibernate, distinct, queryover

I want to try and introduce the `DISTINCT` keyword into SQL, basically I require the following SQL:-

```
SELECT distinct this_.Id          as y0_,
                this_.Name        as y1_,
                this_.Description as y2_,
                this_.UnitPrice   as y3_,
                this_.Director    as y4_
FROM   Product this_
       inner join ActorRole actor1_
         on this_.Id = actor1_.MovieId
WHERE  this_.ProductType = 'Movie'
       AND actor1_.Name like 'm%' /* @p0 */
```

The QueryOver code looks like this, however I can't use the DISTINCT keyword without using a projection:-

```
var movie = Session.QueryOver<Movie>()
  .JoinQueryOver<Actor>(m => m.ActorList).Where(a => a.Name.IsLike("m%"))
  .Select(
    Projections.Distinct(
      Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Property<Movie>(w => w.Id))
        .Add(Projections.Property<Movie>(w => w.Name))
        .Add(Projections.Property<Movie>(w => w.Description))
        .Add(Projections.Property<Movie>(w => w.UnitPrice))
        .Add(Projections.Property<Movie>(w => w.Director))
      )
   )
   .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<Movie>());
return movie.List<Movie>();
```

This works returns me distinct movies where actors begin with the letter 'm'. Now the problem comes as the projection is meant for DTO's and when I iterate over the results and want to lazy load the children. For example:-

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ActorList)
{
  <li>@(item.Name) <em>plays</em> @item.Role</li>
}
```

`Model.ActorList` is always `NULL`, it appears that projecting and using a transformer loses the lazy loading as this method is designed for DTO's. What are my options?

I know I can use a sub query or HQL rather than a `select distinct`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is interested in this then please read the [blog post](http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.com/2011/08/return-parents-based-on-child-filter.html) that explains this behaviour

Comment: You really should post the relevant contents of your blog post to this answer

Answer (score 1):

`Transformers.AliasToBean<Movie>()` just creates a new Movie and fills in the properties. It is therefor a new Movie and not loaded from DB and therefor doesnt inherit the collection of the original Movie. AFAIK `AliasToBean` is to fill ViewModels etc with projected data.

Can't you just use:

```
Session.QueryOver<Movie>()
  .JoinQueryOver<Actor>(m => m.ActorList).Where(a => a.Name.IsLike("m%"))
  .List();
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but this will return duplicate movies if two actor names start with the letter `m%`. I know I can use `.TransformUsing(CriteriaSpecification.DistinctRootEntity)` but this does the filtering on the client. I particularly want to work out if I can use the `DISTINCT` keyword here using the QueryOver goodness!

Comment: Again I could fallback to HQL to get what I want but I am trying to learn QueryOver a bit more and find out where it struggles.

Comment: another option would be a subquery with ids of qanted Movies and then `.Subquery(x => x.Id).In(subquery)`

Comment: Yes I do it this way at the moment, however the optimum sql might be `select distinct movie` with an `inner join` +1 for ideas though :)